# Extrating XML node from Soap

Tags: jaxb

I'm new to JAXB and XML.

I have an XML like

```
<?xml...?>
<ns2:Envelope xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
              xmlns="http://alpha..." 
              xmlns:ns3="http://gama...">
<ns2:Body>
  <ns3:Mynode>
    ...
  </ns3:Mynode>
</ns2:Body>
```

I have a XSD file for Mynode and ran jaxb on it, so I have the class Mynode.java.

I receive a String with an XML, and I parse it like this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
Document doc = docFac.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
NodeList ns3mynode = doc.getElementsByTagName("ns3:Mynode");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Mynode.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
return unmarshaller.unmarshal(node.item(0));
```

but Java throws an exception, saying that he doesn't expect the namespace ns3... that also makes a lot of sense.

Which is the preferred way to extract the ns3:Mynode from the XML, respecting the namespace?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is ok, because nodes inherit the namespace declarations from the parent (you didn't extract the child node, you are just referencing it).  You just forgot to call `setNamespaceAware(true)` on the instance of `DocumentBuilderFactory`.

**Note**

Using DOM in this use case is a bit heavy, below is link to an article on my blog where I do the same thing using JAXB with StAX:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html

Comment: Blaise, thank you very much. It worked. I will look at your blog. Again, thank you.